# Splitting a log file by Regex of datetime

Tags: c#, string, .net-core

I've run into a problem where I need to a parse a heap of lines from a log file.

I want to iterate over every log line in the file and do some work on it.

The issue I'm having is some of the logs SPAN multiple lines and using `File.ReadLines` gives me each line which is fine for the most part but doesn't take into account logs that span multiple lines.

Because of this I've tried to read the whole log file into a single string with `File.ReadAllText` and then trying to split the file by Regex of the DateTime.

`Regex.Split` seems to not get my what I want. It seems to split on every character in the DateTime.

Code:

```
var splitLogs = Regex.Split(log, @"(\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[\s](\d+)[:](\d+)[:](\d+)[.](\d+)", RegexOptions.None);
```

Output:
[image]

I then tried to use `Regex.Matches` instead but it times out in a second. I've tried to add a huge Timespan for expiry but that doesn't change.

Code:

```
Regex.Matches(log, @"(\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[\s](\d+)[:](\d+)[:](\d+)[.](\d+)", RegexOptions.None, Regex.InfiniteMatchTimeout);
```

What's the easiest way to do this? Am I doing something wrong with my `Regex.Split`? I've tried other Stack overflow threads but nothing has worked so far.

Example log:

```
2023-05-02 01:29:26.8784  INFO 137 Log Message Example
2023-05-02 01:29:26.8784  INFO 130 Log Message Example
2023-05-02 01:29:26.8784  INFO 137 Log Message Example
2023-05-02 01:29:26.8784 ERROR 126 Log Message Example Exception thrown
  EXCEPTION: System.Exception:Exception Message
   at  MethodName
   at MethodName
   at MethodName
```

Comment: Why not read by line-by-line and consider if the line is the start of an entry? If the first 24 characters of the line are a valid datetime then it's the start of a line. If there isn't a datetime at the start of the line, then the line is a continuation of the previous entry?

Comment: You can simplify the regex to `(\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[-.\/](\d+)\s(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+)` but it shouldn't really timeout regardless, unless the file is very huge or something. And yeah, splitting to read line by line shouldn't be any sort of issue whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for regular expressions, and reading line-by-line can work. You just need to determine if each line is a new entry or part of the preceding entry. An entry starts with a string which occupies 24 characters and is parseable to a `DateTime`.

Once you know if you have a new entry or the continuation of the previous entry, you can join up data accordingly.

Applying my suggested solution, I came up with this:

```cs
private static async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ReadLogLinesAsync(string file, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var lines = File.ReadLinesAsync(file, cancellationToken);
    StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    await foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        // A new entry will be a line of at least 24 characters in length
        // and will start with a valid DateTime
        bool isNewEntry = line.Length >= 24 
            && DateTime.TryParseExact(line[0..24], "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out _);

        // If the line is a new entry and we have existing data
        // in the StringBuilder then we should return the existing
        // entry and clear the StringBuilder
        if (isNewEntry && lineBuilder.Length > 0)
        {
            yield return lineBuilder.ToString();
            lineBuilder.Clear();
        }

        // Add the current line to the StringBuilder
        // If we already have data, we need to append
        // a newline in between
        if (lineBuilder.Length > 0)
        {
            lineBuilder.AppendLine();
        }
        lineBuilder.Append(line);
    }

    // Finally, if we have any data left in the StringBuilder
    // we should return that entry
    if (lineBuilder.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return lineBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var entries = await ReadLogLinesAsync(@"c:\work\log.txt").ToListAsync();
```

For your sample, it produces a list with the following items:

| Item No. | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "2023-05-02 01:29:26.8784 INFO 137 Log Message Example" |
| 2 | "2023-05-02 01:29:26.8784 INFO 130 Log Message Example" |
| 3 | "2023-05-02 01:29:26.8784 INFO 137 Log Message Example" |
| 4 | "2023-05-02 01:29:26.8784 ERROR 126 Log Message Example Exception thrown\r\n EXCEPTION: System.Exception:Exception Message\r\n at MethodName\r\n at MethodName\r\n at MethodName" |